# select tables from another table name list (SQL tree merge)

Tags: mysql

In my SQL server, I have a "table_list" that record necessary "sub_tables" like this:

```
================
needed_sub_table
----------------
sub_table_1
sub_table_2             <= table_list_1
sub_table_3               
=================

================
needed_sub_table
----------------
sub_table_2
sub_table_6             <= table_list_2
sub_table_9               
=================
```

and in sub_tables, they have exactly same columns with different data :

```
========================
ID  |  name |  parentID
------------------------
1   |  asv  |    0
2   |  asdf |    1             <= sub_table_1
3   |  ggre |    2
========================

========================
ID  |  name |  parentID
------------------------
4   |  uyer |    3
5   |  dfgh |    4             <= sub_table_2
6   |  dhgr |    5
========================
```

What I'm trying to do is : merge "sub_tables" that are listed in "table_list"

And I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT needed_sub_list FROM table_list)
```

but it doesn't work.

What I hope to see is :

```
========================
ID  |  name |  parentID
------------------------
1   |  asv  |    0
2   |  asdf |    1             
3   |  ggre |    2
4   |  uyer |    3
5   |  dfgh |    4             <= result of table_list_1 
6   |  dhgr |    5                (and so for table_list_2....etc.)
========================
```

and since my project might need different combinations of sub_tables,
I must save those combinations in other tables.
This means I can't just merge sub_tables directly because I can only know what sub_tables are needed according to table_lists.
Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(SELECT needed_sub_list FROM table_list)` returns more than one row. So in your statement it should one row for subquery SELECT statements. Probably you get `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.` error

Comment: The output you get is result of a query, that can't be act as main table. If you want above result, you should first take out the result tables and do union operation on them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want just using a basic `UNION` query:

```
SELECT ID, name, parentID
FROM sub_table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, name, parentID
FROM sub_table_2
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: I can't use union directly. Because in my project, required sub_tables are dynamic, and the name of needed sub_tables are listed in a table called "table_list".

Comment: This sounds like bad databaae design, unless it's a homework problem and you are being forced to do it this way.

Comment: any suggestion?